# Concatenating coordinates inside geometryFunction

Tags: openlayers, draw-interaction

While looking [at this example](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/bar/map.control.editionbar.html), I came upon the following code (taken verbatim by using 'view page source'):

```
interaction: new ol.interaction.Draw({
      type: 'Polygon',
      source: vector.getSource(),
      // Count inserted points
      geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
        this.nbpts = coordinates[0].length;
        if (geometry) geometry.setCoordinates([coordinates[0].concat([coordinates[0][0]])]);
        else geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(coordinates);
        return geometry;
      }
    }),
```

I understand what the line starting with `this.nbpts =`  does in that particular example.
What I am most puzzled is the following line:

```
if (geometry) geometry.setCoordinates([coordinates[0].concat([coordinates[0][0]])]);
```

… in particular the weird concatenation it uses at the end. I experimented with replacing the above line with the much simpler:

```
if (geometry) geometry.setCoordinates(coordinates);
```

… and it works equally well, so I don't understand what the `concat` achieves.

Comment: I would say you should ask the author of the cited example Jean-Marc Viglino (https://github.com/Viglino) why he wrote function like this. But one obvious reason for adding first coordinate again as the last coordinate is that polygon is being drawn, which requires first coordinate to be repeated at the end.

Comment: @TomazicM your are correct as regards the use of `concat`. However, the other questions I am asking are still valid without reference to this particular code extract.

Comment: GIS SE site has policy of focused questions, which means one question per question.

Comment: @TomazicM fair enough. I'll edit out the rest and submit separately.

Comment: That is creating a polygon geometry from an array of vertices coordinates.  Polygon rings should be closed by starting and ending at the same point.